# GDPR and cookies that do not store personal data

Tags: cookies

I've created an Opt in / out. If opting in, I enable google analytics and store the decision in a cookie for 30 days. However if i don't store the decision in a cookie at all, then on every page the popup will continue to popup if a user doesn't consent.

Is it ok to store a true / false data in a cookie? Or does that not comply with GDPR?

Comment: Seems according to GDPR, any cookies is considered PII. Under GDPR, “all EU member states must treat cookies and other technical identifiers as personal data.” If not cookies, where to store information about (otherwise) anonymous users? Catch 22?

Answer (score 1):

Both General Data Protection (GDPR) and ePrivacy Regulations (EPR) have to be adhered to, neither one succeeds each other.

Note each European country in-acts GDPR and EPR legislation into law slightly differently from each other some more strict than others. So you should always consult the law for your own European country also.

For the setting use of cookies and other similar technologies, you (data controller)
normally needs user consent as required by Regulation 5(3) of the EPR to use these types of technologies.

However, you don't need consent where the cookie or other technology is
"strictly necessary" to provide you with the service the user is seeking – for example, cookies
which may be needed to provide you with a functioning website which the user wants to
access.

Hence you do not have to ask permission to store "Strictly Necessary" cookies on the users device. Storing a cookie on the users devices to remember the users opt in or out consent of cookies as far as I know is allowed without asking for their permission.

As far as I am aware you are allowed to store that type of cookies for a maximum of 6 months before you have to ask for their opt in consent again. So you could potentially increase from the 1 month you have set.

The exact EU guidelines regarding the "strictly necessary" exception read as follows:

"This shall not prevent any technical storage or access for the sole purpose of carrying out the transmission of a communication over an electronic communications network, or as strictly necessary in order for the provider of an information society service explicitly requested by the subscriber or user to provide the service."

If you are uncertain whether your cookies are strictly necessary, it's best to consult your local regulators. They can provide additional insight and specific guidelines for your country. In general, it is best to err on the side of caution. Unless you absolutely know your cookies are strictly necessary, assume they are not.

On the flip side...

Any cookie that does not fall under the "strictly necessary" definition needs consent before you can store it on a visitor's device.

Nearly all Google and Facebook API services require you to set tracking cookies and marketing cookies on the users devices i.e. you can not use Google/Facebook Login, Google reCapatcha,Google Adsense, Google Analyitics without getting prior consent from the user to set tracking cookies and marketing cookies on the users devices.

It is the trade off of using the free APIs that Google and Facebook offer, they offer the SDKs and APIs for free but require personal information from the user in return.

Google's terms require you to obtain consent from the user before using their APIs and thus setting tracking cookies and marketing cookies on the users device.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not a "catch 22".

In order to store something on user's computer, you must ask permission. The true/false cookie which represents the users consent, can be stored - but also must be done with their consent.

If you consider the true/false cookie "necessary", you can simply ask their permission to store "necessary cookies". In order for the site to work (e.g. don't popup a new window on every page), they must consent to that minimal level.

For example, take a look at what [CookieBot](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/gdpr-cookies/) does:

[image]

"Necessary cookies" are disabled. It cannot be unchecked.